# Phonegap Build Error: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I'm having `BUILD FAILED` everytime I try to build using `phonegap build android --release`. Here's what I get by adding `--verbose`,

```
BUILD FAILED


Total time: 5.791 secs

Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c ""D:\Phonegap Projects\Project - GAMEHOBEY\GameHobe-final\platforms\android\gradlew.bat" cdvBuildRelease -b "D:\Phonegap Projects\Project - GAMEHOBEY\GameHobe-final\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"


(node:3344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:775)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:741)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:88)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1683)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:695)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:592)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:321)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:292)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:54)
    at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:173)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:476)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:787)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1600(Main.java:88)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1722)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:773)
    ... 16 more

1 error; aborting
```

I'm not sure how can I fix this.

Comment: Try `cordova clean` inside your project folder in CMD.